# How do I override ajax-progress-throbber in a theme?

Tags: ajax

In my Drupal 7 site, I created a custom theme. In my theme, I want to change the AJAX progress throbber HTML structure, which by default is the following one.

```
<div class="ajax-progress ajax-progress-throbber"><div class="throbber">&nbsp;</div><div class="message">Please wait...</div></div>
```

I searched a lot about this issue, but I couldn't find any useful document or sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is mostly contained within `misc/ajax.js` file. For example in the `beforeSend` method:

```
  else if (this.progress.type == 'throbber') {
    this.progress.element = $('<div class="ajax-progress ajax-progress-throbber"><div class="throbber">&nbsp;</div></div>');
    if (this.progress.message) {
      $('.throbber', this.progress.element).after('<div class="message">' + this.progress.message + '</div>');
    }
    $(this.element).after(this.progress.element);
  }
```

What I think you would need to do is override this. [Clive provides an answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/73026/57) on how to do just that.

```
(function($) {
  // In mymodule.js, which appears after ajax.js in the page build
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function(xmlhttprequest, options) {
    // Replacement code.
  }
})(jQuery);
```

So your custom file would have to load last or at least after the core file does in order to override it.

Myself, I would probably attempt to create a new progress type, but it looks like other areas override aspects of AJAX callbacks to force throbber as the default, which means you'd have to override more functions and handle that.

Of course, this change above means the throbber would be overridden everywhere it appears in your theme, which may or may not be desired (think Views using AJAX paging, Form AJAX, etc).

Comment: Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend is called before sending ajax command. after receiving data from server which function is called?

Comment: ajaxComplete?? Why?

Comment: because in before send method, I show a full screen modal overlay , but when ajax calling is finished, I must hide full screen modal, I don't know how define ajaxComplete !

Comment: Its in the answer above, you would need to create your own JS file and ensure it loads after ajax.js from Drupal core, and override it. Which essentially in your case means copying 98% of the code over for both and tweaking what you need.

Comment: You could copy the misc.js, make your changes, and swap it so it instead loads your custom misc.js file using [hook_js_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7.x) like in [my answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263924/27710)

Answer (score 7):

For **Drupal 8** there is a new way of doing this as per [this change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2974681)

add the following into the respective files

`THEMENAME.info.yml`

```
libraries-extend:
  core/drupal.ajax:
    - THEMENAME/throbber
```

`THEMENAME.libraries.yml`

```
throbber:
  css:
    css/throbber.css: {}
  js:
    js/throbber.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
```

`js/throbber.js`

```
/**
 * @file
 * Replaced Drupal cores ajax throbber(s), see: https://www.drupal.org/node/2974681
 *
 */
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.theme.ajaxProgressThrobber = function () {
    return "<div class=\"ajax-spinner ajax-spinner--inline\"><span class=\"ajax-spinner__label\">" + Drupal.t('Loading&nbsp;&hellip;', {}, {
      context: "Loading text for Drupal cores Ajax throbber (inline)"
    }) + "</span></div>";
  };
  
  Drupal.theme.ajaxProgressIndicatorFullscreen = function () {
    return "<div class=\"ajax-spinner ajax-spinner--fullscreen\"><span class=\"ajax-spinner__label\">" + Drupal.t('Loading&nbsp;&hellip;', {}, {
      context: "Loading text for Drupal cores Ajax throbber (fullscreen)"
    }) + "</span></div>";
  };
    // You can also customize only throbber message:
    // Drupal.theme.ajaxProgressMessage = message => '<div class="my-message">' + message + '</div>';
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

`css/throbber.css`

```
// optional code of your ajax-spinner classes
```

An **alternative** would be to use the [ajax_loader](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_loader) module which lets you customize the throbber.